# Loop through objects in array, print properties

Tags: javascript, html

I got a situation like this:

```js
var orders = [ 
{ID: "sampleID1", order: "string describing the first order"},
{ID: "sampleID2", order: "string describing the second order"}
];

const bill = document.querySelector("#ordersListed");

for(var x in orders) {
  bill.innerHTML += orders[x].order;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="ordersListed"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Each time I click a button, an item gets added to the array.
I've been trying to loop through the array to print each *order* in a HTML element.

Should show up in the div as:

> string describing the first order
>   string describing the second order

My results:

> first order
>   first order
>   second order

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Please also add HTML and SCRIPT to the snippet to make a [mcve]

Comment: I'd recommend creating real HTML Nodes rather than just appending strings because it gives you so much more control and options with the created list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for...in` is for iterating over `Object` properties, not for `Array`. Use `for...of`:

```js
var orders = [{ ID: "sampleID1", order: "string describing the first order" }, { ID: "sampleID2", order: "string describing the second order" }]

for (order of orders) {
  let para = document.createElement('p')
  para.textContent = order.order
  ordersListed.appendChild(para)
}
```

```css
#ordersListed {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 4px dashed #ddd;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ordersListed"></div>
```

**Note**: I prefer to create real DOM Nodes so I can easily add attributes and attach event handlers. In the second example I show adding title and alerting the order ID on click:

```js
var orders = [{ ID: "sampleID1", order: "string describing the first order" }, { ID: "sampleID2", order: "string describing the second order" }]

for (order of orders) {
  let para = document.createElement('p')
  para.textContent = order.order
  para.title = order.ID
  para.addEventListener('click', function() { alert(this.title) })
  ordersListed.appendChild(para)
}
```

```css
#ordersListed {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 4px dashed #ddd;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

#ordersListed p {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="ordersListed"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just adding a `<br>` to the `innerHTML` in each iteration of Array's `forEach()` will do the trick:

```js
var orders = [ 
  {ID: "sampleID1", order: "string describing the first order"},
  {ID: "sampleID2", order: "string describing the second order"}
];

const bill = document.querySelector("#ordersListed");

orders.forEach(o => bill.innerHTML += o.order + '<br>');
```

```html
<div id="ordersListed"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var orders = [ 
  {ID: "sampleID1", order: "string describing the first order"},
  {ID: "sampleID2", order: "string describing the second order"}
];

for (var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++ ) {
  orderListContainer.textContent += orders[i]['order'];
}
```

As far as I can see you were appending the array element instead of the correct property to the array element.